# Extract values based on last n characters

Tags: r, regex, gsub, qdap

I have a vector like below:

```
vector 
jdjss-jdhs--abc-bec-ndj
kdjska-kvjd-jfj-nej-ndjk
eknd-nend-neekd-nemd-nemdkd-nedke
```

How do I extract the last 3 values so that my result looks like below based on a `-` delimitor:

```
vector                              Col1     Col2    Col3
jdjss-jdhs--abc-bec-ndj              abc      bec     ndj   
kdjska-kvjd-jfj-nej-ndjk             jfj      nej    ndjk
eknd-nend-neekd-nemd-nemdkd-nedke   nemd   nemdkd   nedke
```

I've attemped to use sub and the qdap package but no luck.

```
sub( "(^[^-]+[-][^-]+)(.+$)", "\\2", df$vector)
qdap::char2end(df$vector, "-", 3)
```

Not sure how to go about doing this.

Comment: is double `-`  in `jdhs--abc` a typo?

Comment: it's not a typo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`strcapture`, as a base R corollary to the `tidyr` `extract` answer from Wiktor:

```
strcapture("([^-]*)-([^-]*)-([^-]*)$", df$vector, proto=list(Col1="",Col2="",Col3=""))
#  Col1   Col2  Col3
#1  abc    bec   ndj
#2  jfj    nej  ndjk
#3 nemd nemdkd nedke
```

Answer (score 3):

You may use [`tidyr::extract`](https://rdrr.io/cran/tidyr/man/extract.html):

```
library(tidyr)
vector <- c("jdjss-jdhs--abc-bec-ndj", "kdjska-kvjd-jfj-nej-ndjk", "eknd-nend-neekd-nemd-nemdkd-nedke")
df <- data.frame(vector)
tidyr::extract(df, vector, into = c("Col1", "Col2", "Col3"), "([^-]*)-([^-]*)-([^-]*)$", remove=FALSE)

                             vector Col1   Col2  Col3
1           jdjss-jdhs--abc-bec-ndj  abc    bec   ndj
2          kdjska-kvjd-jfj-nej-ndjk  jfj    nej  ndjk
3 eknd-nend-neekd-nemd-nemdkd-nedke nemd nemdkd nedke
```

The `([^-]*)-([^-]*)-([^-]*)$` pattern matches:

- `([^-]*)` - Group 1 (`'Col1'`): 0+ chars other than `-`
- `-` - a hyphen
- `([^-]*)` - Group 2 (`'Col2'`): 0+ chars other than `-`
- `-` - a hyphen
- `([^-]*)` - Group 3 (`'Col3'`): 0+ chars other than `-`
- `$` - end of string

Set `remove=FALSE` in order to keep the original column.

Answer (score 2):

You can use strsplit from base.

```
    x <- "eknd-nend-neekd-nemd-nemdkd-nedke"

    lastElements <- function(x, last = 3){
      strLength <- length(strsplit(x, "-")[[1]])
      start <- strLength - (last - 1)
      strsplit(x, "-")[[1]][start:strLength]
    }

    > lastElements(x)
    [1] "nemd"   "nemdkd" "nedke"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply split string by `-` using `strsplit` and extract last n elements:

```
df <- data.frame(vector = c(
    "jdjss-jdhs--abc-bec-ndj",
    "kdjska-kvjd-jfj-nej-ndjk",
    "eknd-nend-neekd-nemd-nemdkd-nedke"),
    stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)

cbind(df, t(sapply(strsplit(df$vector, "-"), tail, 3)))

                             vector    1      2     3
1           jdjss-jdhs--abc-bec-ndj  abc    bec   ndj
2          kdjska-kvjd-jfj-nej-ndjk  jfj    nej  ndjk
3 eknd-nend-neekd-nemd-nemdkd-nedke nemd nemdkd nedke
```